# Khinchin's constant: Show that $( \prod_{k=1}^n a_k(x))^{1/n} \longrightarrow K \quad (a.s.)$

Tags: probability-theory, number-theory, ergodic-theory

> Consider the probability space $\Omega = [0,1), \mathcal{A} = \mathcal{B}([0,1))$ and $$\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{1}{\log(2)} \int_A \frac{1}{1+x} dx.$$
> In the lecture we learned that the map $\tau(x)$ with $\tau(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \big\lfloor \frac{1}{x} \big\rfloor$ for $x > 0$ and $\tau(0) = 0$ for $x = 0$ is a measure preserving transformation on $\Omega$ and that for irrational $x \in \Omega$ the $a_i := A(\tau^{i-1}(x))$, where $A(x) := \lfloor 1/x \rfloor$, constitute the continued fraction expansion of $x$, i.e. $x = [0,a_1,a_2,\ldots]$. Furthermore we have already learned that $\tau$ is ergodic.
>
> Use this to show that
>
> $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(a_k(x)) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\log(2)} \int_0^1 \frac{f(\lfloor 1/x \rfloor)}{1+x} dx \qquad (a.s.)$$
>
> for every function $f:[0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\int_0^1 \lvert f(\lfloor 1/x \rfloor ) \rvert dx < \infty$. Conclude that
>
> $$\biggl( \prod_{k=1}^n a_k(x) \biggr)^{1/n} \longrightarrow K \qquad (a.s.)$$
> , where $K := \exp \biggl( \frac{1}{\log(2)} \int_0^1 \frac{\log(\lfloor 1/x \rfloor)}{1+x} dx \biggr)$ is Khinchin's constant.
>
> Remark: The [Wikipedia article on Khinchin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khinchin%27s_constant) proves this, but it uses a different definition of $K$.

I think that the first equation

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(a_k(x)) \longrightarrow \frac{1}{\log(2)} \int_0^1 \frac{f(\lfloor 1/x \rfloor)}{1+x} dx \qquad (a.s.)$$

is just an application of [Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirkhoffsErgodicTheorem.html), but I do not get how to make the conclusion.

Comment: What is $A$ in $a_i=A(\tau^{i-1}(x))$? Furthermore in the definition of Khintchin’s constant you use an $f$ but don’t specify a particular function $f$

Comment: Take $f$ equal to the log function.